# Using variable in read csv command in r

Tags: r

I have a folder with many csv files and I want to make a function that will receive as an argument a numeric range by which the function will pick the selected files (named 1.csv, 2.csv, etc.) and insert them into one data frame. I tried:

```
fun <- function(range){
  for( i in range){
    dat <- read.csv("K:/R program/",i,".csv")
  }
  dat
}
```

I have a few problems. First, I'm probably running over the data each iteration. Second, the read function is not working and making error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are overwriting `dat` at each iteration, and
2. You are passing arguments to `read.csv()`, not pasting parts of the filename into a single string.

The `file.path()` function is usually useful here, but it is more convenient to use `paste0()` here as you have part of the file name in a variable and the extension needs to be added. I might try (making some assumptions about your data)

```
fun <- function(range, ...){
  dat <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(range))
  for (i in seq_along(range)){
    path <- paste0("K:/R program", range[i], ".csv")
    dat[[i]] <- read.csv(file = path, ...)
  }
  dat
}
```

Some explanation, line by line:

1. Create a list object to hold the data
2. Setup loop, but make `i` be an integer index `i` = {1, 2, ..., n}
3. Build up the path using `paste0()`
4. Read the data file and assign it to the `i`th element of `dat`
5. Return `dat`

Answer (score 0):

sprintf should work, like eg

```
for (i in 1:length(urls)) {
  download.file(urls[i], sprintf("~/Desktop/rstats/temp%i.csv.gz", i))
}
```

And to avoid overwriting your data, init the data frame and bind rows in each for-step.

```
df <- data.frame()
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:length(urls)) {
  df.csv <- read.csv(sprintf("~/Desktop/rstats/temp%i.csv", i))
  dummy.df <- df.csv %>% dplyr::select(date, package, version, country)
  df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df, dummy.df)
}
```